# Are there conditions where KL divergence becomes arg-symmetric? Specifically, when KL(X,Y) is maximized. Is KL(Y,X) also maximized?

Tags: statistics, probability

Kullback Liebler divergence is famous asymmetric KL(X,Y) != KL(Y,X).

However let X* be arg_max KL(X,Y).  Then what do we know about KL(Y,X*)?  Is it as large as possible?

Suppose I have a binary variable Y and a much more complicated, multidimensional (but discrete) distribution X.

If I find an X that maximizes KL(X,Y) then does that X also maximize KL(Y,X)  (for the same Y).

Suppose the outcome Y is getting a loan.  Only 10% of people in the dataset get a loan. P(Y) = .1

However, among white males the probability of getting a loan increases to 20%  P(Y|white,male) = .2

Furthermore, lets say white males make up 30% of the dataset P(WM) = .30

From this we can also deduce that WM get 60% of all loans P(WM | Y) = .6

We get

```
    KL(WM,Y) = .2 * ln(.2/.1)  + .8 *ln(.8/.9)
```

In the other direction we have

```
    KL(Y,WM)  = .6 * ln(.6/.3)  + .4 *ln(.4 / .7)
```

Now obviously these 2 values do not equal eachother. However, can we prove that no other X will increase KL(Y,WM) higher than this?

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com or math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You want to MAXIMIZE KL? Standard problem is to minimize KL, which is equivalent to maximizing likelihood